# Vagrant permissions issue

Tags: permissions, vagrant, chmod

Here is my vagrant file. The problem is inside `var/www I can't set particular folder's permissions using the configuration below. For example, var/www/sample folder must be set 777 permission. But I can't do it, neither using root nor vagrant accounts. Tried to change moun's type into rsync. Still the same problem.

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

# check and install required Vagrant plugins
required_plugins = ["vagrant-hostmanager"]
required_plugins.each do |plugin|
    if Vagrant.has_plugin?(plugin) then
        system "echo OK: #{plugin} already installed"
    else
        system "echo Not installed required plugin: #{plugin} ..."
        system "vagrant plugin install #{plugin}"
    end
end

Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"

  config.ssh.shell = "bash -c 'BASH_ENV=/etc/profile exec bash'"

  config.vm.provision :shell,
    keep_color: true,
    path: "provision/setup.sh"

  config.vm.box_check_update = true

  config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.56.10"

  config.vm.synced_folder '.', '/vagrant', disabled: true
  config.vm.synced_folder "./", "/var/www", create: true, group: "vagrant", owner: "vagrant", type: "rsync"

   config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
     vb.name = "Web Server"
     vb.gui = false
     vb.memory = "512"
   end


end
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

change to

```
config.vm.synced_folder "./", "/var/www", group: "vagrant", owner: "vagrant", mount_options: ["dmode=777, fmode=664"]
```

This makes the directory with 777 mode and files with 664 - you can adjust those values based on your needs